# Passing multiple values for same GET variable in URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to pass multiple variables in a GET request than the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepage?tags[]=one&tags[]=two&tags[]=three
```

I had thought about the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepage?tags=one,two,three
```

Then using `explode()` to separate them.

Wondered if anyone had seen or used a better solution though?

Comment: How about `http:/who.cares/page.php?tags=lorem+ipsum+sit+dolor+amet` .. or with mode rewrite: `http://who.cares/tags/lorem+ipsum+sit+dolor+amet`. With `urldecode()` and explode on `' '`.

Comment: Why would you want to do so? The mechanism works; Every mechanism you will invent will have it's flaws, but then you are on your own.

Comment: @twall: to make it look nice for the user if it ever used as a link etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `explode()` is only reliable if the values of each tag will *never* contain whatever string it is you're exploding by (in this case ",").

I'd say it's safer to use `tags[]=X&tags[]=Y`.

Answer (score 1):

you can  urlencode(json_encode(yourData)), then on the server json_decode

this solution will work with any complex data you may need to pass, not just the simple one you have here.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution is using `json_encode()`. But if you want to look nice (as a single string). You can encyrpt code to look like `page?tags=HuH&ITBHjYF86588gmjkbkb`. Simplest of doing it is

```
$tags = base64_encode(json_encode($tags_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using mod_rewrite to rewrite like www.website.com/tags/tag1-tag2-tag3 or if you want to use only php www.website.com/tags.php?tags=tag1-tag2-tag3. Using the '-' makes it searchengine friendly (as for tags is often useful) and is also not as commonly used as a comma (thinking of the tagging itself).