# passing multiple values in a url

Tags: php, mysql

have a database with a list of business leads. They are all given a status of New, Hot, Cold, etc. I have links on the page to display only the New or only Hot that work fine, but I can't seem to get one working to display All. The default view is New. Here is what I'm working with, thanks in advance for your help.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";

if(isset($_GET['contactstatus'])
&& in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed')))
{      
$status = $_GET['contactstatus'];   
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus ORDER BY date DESC";  
}

if(isset($_GET['contactstatus'])
&& in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed')))
{      
$status = $_GET['contactstatus'];   
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY date DESC";  
}
```

The url that I'm using to get all is:

www.mydomain.com/leads.php?contactstatus=New&contactstatus=Hot&contactstatus=Cold&contactstatus=Rejected&contactstatus=Closed

I've also tried:

www.mydomain.com/leads.php?contactstatus=New&Hot&Cold&Rejected&Closed

Comment: Are you trying to get All leads to show if no status type is passed through the URL, or have links which allow you to pass more than one contact status through the get string?

Comment: I'm trying to have an "All" link which shows all statuses. The default on the page should be leads with status "New" only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to pass the same variable through the address have you tried using an array otherwise you are overwriting the get variable.

Like so [www.mydomain.com/leads.php?contactstatus[]=New&contactstatus[]=Hot&contactstatus[]=Cold&contactstatus[]=Rejected&contactstatus[]=Closed](http://www.mydomain.com/leads.php?contactstatus%5b%5d=New&contactstatus%5b%5d=Hot&contactstatus%5b%5d=Cold&contactstatus%5b%5d=Rejected&contactstatus%5b%5d=Closed)

```
$status_types = Array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed');

$statuses = Array();
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM contacts ';
for($i=0, $j=count($_GET['contactstatus']); $i<$j; $i++){
    if(in_array($_GET['contactstatus'][$i], $status_types)){
        if($i==0)
            $query.= " WHERE contactstatus IN (";

        $statuses[] = $_GET['contactstatus'][$i];
        $query .= "'".$_GET['contactstatus'][$i]."'";
        if($i==($j-1))
            $query .= ")";

    }
}
$query .= ' ORDER BY contacts.date DESC';
```

I have set this up to automaticly **select all** if no contactstatus is passed.

Comment: hmm, not getting it to work. I'm learning so you lost me at $i & $j stuff. The default view is to show New `$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC"` then I have `if(isset($_GET['contactstatus']) && in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed'))) { $status = $_GET['contactstatus']; $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY date DESC"; }` All the parameters in the URL work fine individually, I'm trying to create one that displays All contacts regardless of status. Thank you!

Comment: These tutorials were helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp, http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Here is what I learned, maybe you can help me from here and correct me if I'm wrong: `for($i=0, $j=count($GET['contactstatus']); $i<$j: $i++` --  this is just telling it to loop and continue to while $i is less than $j `if(in_array($GET['contactstatus'][$i], $status_types` -- this searches status_types for $i? or for contactstatus? (confused here) `if($i==0) $query.= " WHERE contactstatus IN (";` -- means if $i equals 0 where contactstaus is array...i'm now lost. The code above works for the individual statuses but I still can't figure out how to pull all statuses and have the default be New.

Comment: I've been working on this for 2 days now and cant' get it to work, can you offer any more help?

Comment: Sorry Josh I was away for the weekend, if you do not pass any contactstatus' through the query string you will get all the results. The pseudo of what the code above is doing, is this: I set up a basic query $query then I concatenate extra parts as and when the need for them exists. So if the for doesn't run once (because the length of $_GET['contactstatus'] is zero [as in it has no values]) then the query will be just: SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY contacts.date DESC.

Comment: The for loop works like this there are three parts the initialiser the condition and the iterator all separated by ; the first part happens when the loop starts, the next part is what the condition of the loop is to keep going and the third part is what to do each time. In this instance I am setting up to integers i which is our counter which starts at zero and j which is the length of the array that we passed through the query string, the third part i++ is incrementing the integer once per loop so that we can navigate the contents of $_GET['contactstatus']

Comment: within the loop I am adding the statuses that are selected to $statuses (because you seemed to be doing this) and each of the values of contactstatus to the query, also if it is the first time the loop is run if($i==0)
I am adding the syntax to make the query work and if it is the last I am closing it. I am also checking that the choice exists in the available options, I am doing this so that the user does not pass things we do not want through this value.

Answer (score 0):

The first if looks the same as the second. You're also missing the WHERE qualifier on the first query.

If you want to get all of the contacts, change this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";
```

to this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY contacts.date DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just set the default behavior of your php page to display all?  That is, if no `$_GET` parameter is set (in the URL), your page simply selects all leads from database.

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM `contacts` ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result && $result->num_rows > 0){
    // do something with all leads
}
```

To deal with specific statuses, we have

```
if( isset($_GET['contactstatus']) ){
// select leads based on status 
}
```

If you want to pass multiple values to a single GET parameter, see [Passing multiple values for same GET variable in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941553/passing-multiple-values-for-same-get-variable-in-url)

Comment: The default view is to show New `$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC"` then I have `if(isset($_GET['contactstatus'])
&& in_array($_GET['contactstatus'], array('New', 'Hot', 'Warm', 'Cold', 'Rejected', 'Closed')))
{ 
$status = $_GET['contactstatus']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contactstatus = '".$status."' ORDER BY date DESC"; 
}` All the parameters in the URL work fine individually, I'm trying to create one that also displays All.